# Static hierarchy toggle table

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a hierarchy list, and make subgroups toggle as the user clicks on category names, but this doesn't seem to work. How can I do?

https://jsfiddle.net/p9737fqa/

```
<h1><a href onclick="$('div.l1').toggle('fast');">Level 1</a></h1>
<div class="l1">
    <p>Entry 1</p>
    <p>Entry 2</p>
    <h2><a href onclick="$('div.l2').toggle('fast');">Level 2</a></h2>
    <div class="l2">
        <p>Entry 3</p>
        <h3><a href onclick="$('div.l3').toggle('fast');">Level 3</a></h3>
            <div class="l3">
            <p>Entry 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h2><a href onclick="$('div.l2').toggle('fast');">Level 2</a></h2>
    <div class="l2">
        <p>Entry 5</p>
        <h3><a href onclick="$('div.l3').toggle('fast');">Level 3</a></h3>
        <div class="l3">
            <p>Entry 6</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: problem fixed, but is there an easy way to toggle nearest level X? for example, when i click level 2 both level 2s toggle :/
https://jsfiddle.net/p9737fqa/3/

Comment: Improved the formatting and grammar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try .`next()` and `.parent()`

```js
$(function() {
  $('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().next('div[class^=l]').toggle('fast');
  }).trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><a href="#">Level 1</a></h1>
<div class="l1">
  <p>Entry 1</p>
  <p>Entry 2</p>
  <h2><a  href="#">Level 2</a></h2>
  <div class="l2">
    <p>Entry 3</p>
    <h3><a  href="#">Level 3</a></h3>
    <div class="l3">
      <p>Entry 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2><a href="#">Level 2</a></h2>
  <div class="l2">
    <p>Entry 5</p>
    <h3><a  href="#">Level 3</a></h3>
    <div class="l3">
      <p>Entry 6</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[You should `return false;`](https://jsfiddle.net/p9737fqa/2/) after all functions on onclick, since the links would refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks :) just so i don't make new questions, can i somehow make nearest level toggle, not all levels with same number?
https://jsfiddle.net/p9737fqa/3/ if you click level 2, both level 2 toggle :/ is there easy way to only make nearest level 2 toggle?